# twitter authorization using r

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis

```
    >library(base64enc)
    > options(httr_oauth_cache=T)
    > library(twitteR)
    > access_token <- 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    > consumer_key <- 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    > consumer_secret <- 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    > access_secret <- 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    > setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,access_secret)
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

I am not able to connect twitter to R.

Could you please help me out with it in the authentication?

Comment: Have you given permission for your app to connect? Add localhost to webserver in Twitter API

Comment: Have you changed your Callback URL to http://127.0.0.1:1410?